# What is the impact on performance of localStorage in an Ionic app?

Tags: ionic-framework, local-storage, angular-local-storage

I'm working on a mobile app using the Ionic framework and am using localStorage for caching purposes. I would like to know whether the usage of localStorage can negatively impact the performance of my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is depending on your application ,You could use localStorage because localstorage plays major role in app development ,  but in some cases it is affecting app's performance ,

You should consider

- You should replace localStorage values frequently , Because once you set value it will not be changed unless you change ,
- If the application Goes with large data , You have to choose Sqlite
- Avoid storing complex data in localStorage , because you should not play with code logic with the help of localStorage .

Answer (score -1):

You can use caching as show in below code:

```
.state('app.userlist', {
     cache : false,
     url: "/userlist",
             views: {
             'menuContent': {
             templateUrl: "templates/userlist.html",
             controller: 'UserListCtrl'
     }
 }
})
```